# Can I refer to a token dynamically in Splunk?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

New to Splunk...

Not sure if there is a way to do this.

Let's say I have a token

```
<set token="token_1">one</set>
<set token="token_2">two</set>
```

Let's say I have another token:

```
<set token="qualifer">1</set>
```

Can I then do something like

```
<eval token="value"> token_{qualifer} </eval>
```

and basically set value to one (the value of token_1)?  Effectively...

```
<set token="value"> one </set>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tokens in Splunk are referenced by enclosing the token name in `$`.

```
<eval token="value">token_$qualifer$</eval>
```

should work.

But what you want is a nested token reference, which would look something like this:

```
<eval token="value">$token_$qualifer$$</eval>
```

I'm not sure it will work.